# Creating array from two arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having troubles trying to create a certain array. Basicly, I have an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12341241
        [type] => "Blue"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 52454235
        [type] => "Blue"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 848437437
        [type] => "Blue"
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 387372723
        [type] => "Blue"
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 73732623
        [type] => "Blue"
    )
```

...

Next, I have an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 34141
        [type] => "Red"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 253532
        [type] => "Red"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 94274
        [type] => "Red"
    )
```

I want to construct an array, which is a combination of the two above, using this rule: after 3 Blues, there must be a Red:

```
Blue1
Blue2
Blue3
Red1
Blue4
Blue5
Blue6
Red2
Blue7
Blue8
Blue9
Red3
```

Note that the their can be more Red's than Blue's, but also more Blue's than Red's. If the Red's run out, it should begin with the first one again.

Example: let's say there are only two Red's:

```
Blue1
Blue2
Blue3
Red1
Blue4
Blue5
Blue6
Red2
Blue7
Blue8
Blue9
Red1
...
```

...

If the Blue's run out, the Red's should append until they run out too.
Example: let's say there are 5 Blue's, and 5 Red's:

```
Blue1
Blue2
Blue3
Red1
Blue4
Blue5
Red2
Red3
Red4
Red5
```

Note: the arrays come from mysql-fetches. Maybe it's better to fetch them while building the new array?

Anyway, the while-loops got to me, I can't figure it out...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: seems like very simple algorithm to me

Comment: So you already have an array of blues, and an array of reds, and the problem is just interleaving them?

Comment: Why the tag MySQL? If both arrays are coming from a MySQL db, you maybe can create the final array with SQL, but therefore you need to show  us the db structure

Comment: @Reeno I have a feeling, trying to do this in MySQL would create unnecessary overhead on the DB. Doing it within PHP code is better I think, in this case

Comment: So why don't you just write a loop then?

Comment: I'm able to add the reds, but when they run out, I can't force them to start over as long as there are blues...

Comment: @binoculars That's a good start, add your current code to the question so we can help you

Comment: @binoculars: You want to traverse the arrays iterator-style, e.g. with `each`. This allows you to respond to the reds running out simply with `reset($reds)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier than you (and others) seem to think:

```
$r = 0;
foreach($blues as $c => $v) {
    $out []= $v;
    if(($c + 1) % 3 == 0)
        $out []= $reds[$r++ % count($reds)];
}

$out = array_merge($out, array_slice($reds, $r));
```

The modulus cares for cycling, and the last line appends the rest of reds (if any) to the result.

https://ideone.com/cxANRW

Comment: This is why I consult Stackoverflow... When my solution is taken up more lines than it should, there's always a smarter solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$blue = array (
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 12341241
    [type] => "Blue"
)

[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 52454235
    [type] => "Blue"
)

[2] => Array
(
    [id] => 848437437
    [type] => "Blue"
)

[3] => Array
(
    [id] => 387372723
    [type] => "Blue"
)

[4] => Array
(
    [id] => 73732623
    [type] => "Blue"
));

$red = array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 34141
        [type] => "Red"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 253532
        [type] => "Red"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 94274
        [type] => "Red"
    )
);
$mixed = array();
$index = $b = $r = 0;
if (count($blue) > count($red)){
   $counter = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i<count($blue) ; $i++){
      $mixed [$index] = $blue[$b];
      $b++;
      $index++;
      if ($r == count($red))
         $r=0;
      if ($counter == 3){
          $counter =0;
          $mixed[$index] = $red[$r];
          $r++;
      }
    $counter++;
   }
}
else {
     $counter = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i<count($red) ; $i++){
      $mixed [$index] = $blue[$b];
      $b++;
      $index++;
      if ($counter == 3 or $b == count($blue)){
          $counter =0;
          $mixed[$index] = $red[$r];
          $r++;
      }
    $counter++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$blue_array = array(array('id'=>'121','type'=>'blue'),array('id'=>'122','type'=>'blue'),array('id'=>'123','type'=>'blue'),array('id'=>'124','type'=>'blue'),array('id'=>'125','type'=>'blue'),array('id'=>'125','type'=>'blue'));   
$red_array = array(array('id'=>'123','type'=>'red'),array('id'=>'123','type'=>'red'),array('id'=>'123','type'=>'red'),array('id'=>'123','type'=>'red'));
$result_array = array();
$blue_count = 1;
$red_count = 1;
// Go through $blue_array first
foreach($blue_array as $blue) {
    // Shove an item from $red_array for every 3 $blue_array items
    if($blue_count % 3 == 0) {
        $result_array[] = 'Blue' . $blue_count;
        if(count($red_array) > 0) {
            $temp = array_shift($red_array);
            $result_array[] = 'Red' . $red_count;
            $red_count++;
        }
    } else {
        $result_array[] = 'Blue' . $blue_count;
    }
    $blue_count++;
}
// Add remaining $red_array items to $result_array
foreach($red_array as $red) {
    $result_array[] = 'Red' . $red_count;
    $red_count++;
}
print_r($result_array);
```